# Jekyll site crash render after push to github pages

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

Guys, I need your's help...I'm build jekyll site, just empty site with one post on page. After deploying to github-pages, site looks bad, with wrong layout and render, however on localhost site looks good.

What I mean, it's showing on screenshots:

Screenshot my page if I'm use localhost - http://savepic.net/6562245.htm
Screenshot after push&deploy to github-pages - http://savepic.net/6588868.htm

What wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're at the root of your `spbvasilenko.github.io` subdomain you have to set:

```
 baseurl: ""
```

Comment: # Site settings
title: NSVasilenko
email: spb.vasilenko@gmail.com
description: > # this means to ignore newlines until "baseurl:"
  This blog contains every weekly articles about iOS Development
baseurl: "" # the subpath of your site, e.g. /blog/
url: "" # the base hostname & protocol for your site
twitter_username: ivasilenko
github_username:  spbvasilenko

Comment: It was `/blog/` ten minutes ago. So now it works. You can then approve my answer.